# podman starts mysql container, and there will be permission problems when using podman volume

Tags: mysql, macos, podman, podman-compose

## podman version and OS

podman version：podman version 4.7.2
Operating System：macOS Monterey
podman-compose version: 1.0.6

## Problem Description

Write the yaml file and start the container using podman compose. There is no permission to use the volume mounting directory in the yaml file. The following is the content of the yaml file:

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0.35
    container_name: mysql8
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 12345678
    ports:
      - 13306:3306
    user: mysql
    volumes:
      - ./mysql_volumes/data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./mysql_volumes/config:/etc/mysql/conf.d
      - ./mysql_volumes/logs:/var/log/mysql
      - ./mysql_volumes/init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

# container network
networks:
  default:
    name: mysql-net
    driver: bridge
```

podman logs -f container_id outputs the following log information:

```
2023-11-24 11:42:25+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.35-1.el8 started.
2023-11-24 11:42:25+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
mysqld: [Warning] World-writable config file '/etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf' is ignored.
2023-11-24T11:42:25.829548Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
2023-11-24T11:42:25.829942Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.35) initializing of server in progress as process 36
2023-11-24T11:42:25.835507Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive
2023-11-24T11:42:25.840692Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-11-24T11:42:26.015975Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012592] [InnoDB] Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
2023-11-24T11:42:26.016240Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012595] [InnoDB] The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to the directory.
2023-11-24T11:42:26.016302Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-013183] [InnoDB] Assertion failure: log0files_governor.cc:1547:err == DB_SUCCESS thread 281473385119616
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
2023-11-24T11:42:26Z UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
Most likely, you have hit a bug, but this error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
BuildID[sha1]=666ff782b6ef10983c1529c4607aae3ecbc7150e
Thread pointer: 0x441dab30
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = ffffa1223640 thread_stack 0x100000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace(unsigned char const*, unsigned long)+0x44) [0x1dfd9e4]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(print_fatal_signal(int)+0x2a0) [0xf17b10]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_server_abort()+0xa4) [0xf17d54]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_abort()+0x14) [0x1df7624]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(ut_dbg_assertion_failed(char const*, char const*, unsigned long)+0x270) [0x20050e0]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(log_files_create(log_t&, unsigned long)+0x378) [0x1edd478]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(log_sys_init(bool, unsigned long, unsigned long&)+0x704) [0x1eed874]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(srv_start(bool)+0xb88) [0x1fbf268]
/usr/sbin/mysqld() [0x1e415bc]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(dd::bootstrap::DDSE_dict_init(THD*, dict_init_mode_t, unsigned int)+0x70) [0x1bddfa0]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(dd::bootstrap::initialize(THD*)+0x84) [0x1be1ac4]
/usr/sbin/mysqld() [0xfc4660]
/usr/sbin/mysqld() [0x245eab8]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x7950) [0xffffa2892950]
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x23e1c) [0xffffa2021e1c]

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (0): Connection ID (thread ID): 1
Status: NOT_KILLED

The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
2023-11-24 11:42:26+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.35-1.el8 started.
2023-11-24 11:42:26+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
mysqld: [Warning] World-writable config file '/etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf' is ignored.
2023-11-24T11:42:26.277274Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
2023-11-24T11:42:26.277445Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.35) initializing of server in progress as process 36
2023-11-24T11:42:26.279170Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010457] [Server] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting.
2023-11-24T11:42:26.279174Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013236] [Server] The designated data directory /var/lib/mysql/ is unusable. You can remove all files that the server added to it.
2023-11-24T11:42:26.279440Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2023-11-24T11:42:26.279505Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.35)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2023-11-24 11:42:26+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.35-1.el8 started.
2023-11-24 11:42:26+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
mysqld: [Warning] World-writable config file '/etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf' is ignored.
2023-11-24T11:42:26.504825Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
```

Remove user from the yaml file, and the log information of starting the container is:

```
2023-11-24 11:48:14+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.35-1.el8 started.
chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/mysql/': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/mysql/ibdata1': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/mysql/.DS_Store': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/mysql/#innodb_redo': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/mysql/#ib_16384_1.dblwr': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/mysql/#ib_16384_0.dblwr': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/mysql/auto.cnf': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/mysql': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/mysql/ibdata1': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/mysql/.DS_Store': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/mysql/#innodb_redo': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/mysql/#ib_16384_1.dblwr': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/mysql/#ib_16384_0.dblwr': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/mysql/auto.cnf': Operation not permitted
```

I modified the permissions of the four directories: config, data, init, and logs.

```
chmod 777 config
chmod 777 data
chmod 777 init
chmod 777 logs
```

There is still a problem when starting the mysql container. The output log information of podman logs -f container_id is:

```
2023-11-24 11:42:25+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.35-1.el8 started.
2023-11-24 11:42:25+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
mysqld: [Warning] World-writable config file '/etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf' is ignored.
2023-11-24T11:42:25.829548Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
2023-11-24T11:42:25.829942Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.35) initializing of server in progress as process 36
2023-11-24T11:42:25.835507Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive
2023-11-24T11:42:25.840692Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-11-24T11:42:26.015975Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012592] [InnoDB] Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
2023-11-24T11:42:26.016240Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012595] [InnoDB] The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to the directory.
2023-11-24T11:42:26.016302Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-013183] [InnoDB] Assertion failure: log0files_governor.cc:1547:err == DB_SUCCESS thread 281473385119616
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
2023-11-24T11:42:26Z UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
Most likely, you have hit a bug, but this error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
BuildID[sha1]=666ff782b6ef10983c1529c4607aae3ecbc7150e
Thread pointer: 0x441dab30
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = ffffa1223640 thread_stack 0x100000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace(unsigned char const*, unsigned long)+0x44) [0x1dfd9e4]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(print_fatal_signal(int)+0x2a0) [0xf17b10]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_server_abort()+0xa4) [0xf17d54]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_abort()+0x14) [0x1df7624]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(ut_dbg_assertion_failed(char const*, char const*, unsigned long)+0x270) [0x20050e0]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(log_files_create(log_t&, unsigned long)+0x378) [0x1edd478]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(log_sys_init(bool, unsigned long, unsigned long&)+0x704) [0x1eed874]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(srv_start(bool)+0xb88) [0x1fbf268]
/usr/sbin/mysqld() [0x1e415bc]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(dd::bootstrap::DDSE_dict_init(THD*, dict_init_mode_t, unsigned int)+0x70) [0x1bddfa0]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(dd::bootstrap::initialize(THD*)+0x84) [0x1be1ac4]
/usr/sbin/mysqld() [0xfc4660]
/usr/sbin/mysqld() [0x245eab8]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x7950) [0xffffa2892950]
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x23e1c) [0xffffa2021e1c]

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (0): Connection ID (thread ID): 1
Status: NOT_KILLED

The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
2023-11-24 11:42:26+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.35-1.el8 started.
2023-11-24 11:42:26+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
mysqld: [Warning] World-writable config file '/etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf' is ignored.
2023-11-24T11:42:26.277274Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
2023-11-24T11:42:26.277445Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.35) initializing of server in progress as process 36
2023-11-24T11:42:26.279170Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010457] [Server] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting.
2023-11-24T11:42:26.279174Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013236] [Server] The designated data directory /var/lib/mysql/ is unusable. You can remove all files that the server added to it.
2023-11-24T11:42:26.279440Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2023-11-24T11:42:26.279505Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.35)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2023-11-24 11:42:26+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.35-1.el8 started.
2023-11-24 11:42:26+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
mysqld: [Warning] World-writable config file '/etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf' is ignored.
2023-11-24T11:42:26.504825Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a command just below your image to make it case insensitive

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0.35
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password --lower_case_table_names=1
    container_name: mysql8
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 12345678
    ports:
      - 13306:3306
    user: mysql
    volumes:
      - ./mysql_volumes/data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./mysql_volumes/config:/etc/mysql/conf.d
      - ./mysql_volumes/logs:/var/log/mysql
      - ./mysql_volumes/init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```